# Complex impedances of capacitors/inductors in the phasor domain

Tags: circuit-analysis, phasor, circuit-theory

I'm trying to verify the complex impedances of passive components in the **phasor domain** (not s-domain). Take for example the inductor, whose element law is \$ v = L \frac{di}{dt} \$. Assuming a complex exponential current drive where \$ i = I e^{j \omega t}\$ (where \$I\$ is a phasor) then we get: \$ v = L I (j \omega)e^{j \omega t} \$. From this we see that the voltage will also be a complex exponential with a phasor \$ V = (j \omega) L I \$, and so the complex impedance is \$ j \omega L \$ as expected. This works fine.

I'm trying to do the same thing assuming a complex exponential voltage instead of assuming a complex exponential current, which means I need to do an integral instead: \$ i(t) = \frac{1}{L} \int_{0}^{t} v(\tau)d \tau + i(0)\$. Plugging in \$ v(t)=Ve^{j \omega t} \$ and evaluating the integral, I get: \$ i(t) = \frac{V}{j \omega L} e^{j \omega t} + (i(0) - \frac{V}{j \omega L})\$. If it weren't for the term in parentheses then this would be the expected result. If I assume that \$ i(0) = \frac{V}{j \omega L} \$ then it works out. Is this calculation and assumption about the initial current correct, and if so is it just a mathematical requirement without a conceptual reason? Have I made an error somewhere?

Side comments: my understanding is that typically in the time domain capacitors and inductors need to have zero initial condition or else they are technically not linear components (for example, a zero input can give you a nonzero output, which linear systems by definition can't do; and yes, I know that you could model the initial condition as a separate dependent source). Here it looks like you need to assume the initial condition to be a certain nonzero value in order for the component to be linear in the phasor domain.

It's interesting that in the s-domain, you assume that the initial state is zero in order to get linear s-domain components (or alternatively you model the initial condition as a separate independent source). [See here for reference.](http://ocw.nthu.edu.tw/ocw/upload/12/244/12handout.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of your question is

> is it just a mathematical requirement without a conceptual reason?

Recall that the exponential notation is for the stationary case. In other words, it assumes that the voltage oscillation has been applied for an infinite amount of time prior to t=0. Practically this assumption is satisfied when any transient effects, after starting for instance with v(0)=V and I(0)=0, have died out well before t=0, and only a pure and constant sinusoidal oscillation remains at t>0.

You can also cut into t=0, and start a pure and constant sinusoidal oscillation by applying the appropriate initial conditions as though the transients have settled. In your case this means starting with v(0) = V and i(0) as mathematically calculated in your question, and letting the system oscillate with v(t) after that.

This is a real physical concept. In linear systems, transients can be entirely eliminated by initializing the system with appropriate initial conditions, as you have done.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response, I think this conceptually makes sense to me. So is it the case that the initial condition on the inductor gets "forced" to be V/jL or do I as the person stating the problem need to specify "the initial condition on the inductor (the current i(0) is such that there are no transient effects throughout the entire current signal"? I hope that question makes sense.

Comment: After going back to the math and also doing some simulation I think I answered it. So depending on the initial condition that one imposes on the inductor, it may demonstrate transient behavior or not. Choosing an initial complex current value also chooses an initial real current value which you can get by taking the real part of the complex initial current. It seems that the upshot of all this is that when doing steady state phasor analysis, by insisting that we can *always* define a complex impedance such that V = I * Z, we are implicitly forcing the initial current to be that value.

Comment: (Probably) final comment: so it does seem to be the case then that as opposed to s-domain circuit models where you choose the initial condition on the circuit to be 0 in order for the circuit component itself to be linear in that domain, in the phasor domain circuit model in order for the circuit component to be linear you choose the initial condition which is consistent with the lack of a transient response.